# How to make data stored in filter of dictionary keys not case sensitive

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, key

I have a code that picks up a value from input sheet and searches sheet 2.

If input sheet value is "Hello Dear" and in sheet 2, is "hello dear", it is throwing an error.

```
For lngRowSource = 2 To rngFirstTable.Rows.Count

'   Copy the "header info" columns
rngDisplay.Resize(1, 3).Value = rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value

'   Extract the relevant dictionary corresponding to HR Role HR Position    
Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 3).Value)

'   Use the array from .items() to transpose to array equiv to range
rngDisplay.Offset(0, 4).Resize(dicTasks.Count, 1).Value = _
Application.Transpose(dicTasks.Items())

'   Increment the offset from the top left cell
lngRowDest = lngRowDest + dicTasks.Count
Set rngDisplay = rngDisplayTopLeft.Offset(lngRowDest - 1, 0)
Set dicTasks = Nothing

Next lngRowSource
```

I get

> run time error 424 ; object required

in the line `Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 3).Value)`

Can I make it non-case sensitive?

Comment: Without thinking toooo much about whats going on: does lcase(xxx) help? if you dont want case sensitivity, then just telling excel to make your strings lower case, then compare them, might help?

Comment: @czeskleba : tried it..but no luck

Comment: okidoki, then I have to think about whats actually going on in the code, I was hoping I could avoid that xD. Gimme a few

Comment: Can you post more of the code? what does dicFilter do for example? Maybe I'm not the right person. I have no clue whats going on from this snippet, sorry.

Comment: If `dicTasks` it's an Object, line `Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 3).Value)` makes no sense. If it's a variable just to store a value, remove `Set`. When assigning values into variables, you just do `Variable=value`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Please find my initializations below :

Dim rngFirstTable As Excel.Range,
Dim rngSecondTable As Excel.Range,
Dim dicFilter As New Scripting.Dictionary,
Dim dicTasks As Scripting.Dictionary,
Dim rngInspect As Excel.Range,
Dim lngRowSource As Long,
Dim lngRowDest As Long,
Dim rngDisplayTopLeft As Range,
Dim rngDisplay As Range,

Comment: Do not post that info on comments, because it's hard to read. Edit your original question and add that new extra info :) Also, what error number are you getting?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns : its run time error 424 ; object required

Comment: Use lcase (or ucase) when you build the dictionary, ie dictFilter.add lcase(key), value and the same when you retrieve them, value = dictFilter(lcase(key)).